# How do I add jobs to an organizational set with the Kronos XML API?

Tags: xml, kronos-workforce-central

I want to use the Kronos Workforce Central XML API to add a job to an organizational set.

According to the [*WFC v6.3 Timekeeping Developer's Toolkit Guide*](https://community.kronos.com/s/article/Workforce-Timekeeper-v6-3-Developer-s-Toolkit-Reference-Guide), I should be able to add jobs by using `Action="UpdateEntryList"` with the `<OrgSet>`, and `<OrgSetEntry>` with `AddEntries`.

```
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0">
    <Request Action="UpdateEntryList">
        <OrgSet OrgSetName="ORG SET NAME">
            <EntryList>
                <OrgSetEntry
                  EffectiveDate="02/09/2018"
                  AddEntries="ROOT/BU/DIVISION/SERVICE LINE/DEPT/JOB"/>
            </EntryList>
        </OrgSet>
    </Request>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

However, the server returns an error stating that `AddEntries` can't be used with `UpdateEntryList`.

```
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0" WFCVersion="6.3.13.362" TimeStamp="2/09/2018 2:11PM GMT-05:00">
    <Response Status="Failure" Action="UpdateEntryList">
        <Error Message="WFP-01133 A property contains a value, no value is allowed for
          that property for the action - Property: AddEntries, Action: UpdateEntryList."
          ErrorCode="1223" ActionName="UpdateEntryList" PropertyName="AddEntries"/>
    </Response>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

How can I add a job to an organizational set with the Kronos Workforce Central XML API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a job to an `<OrgSet>` with `UpdateEntryList`, specify the job's path in the `Name` attribute.

```
<Kronos_WFC version="1.0">
    <Request Action="UpdateEntryList">
        <OrgSet OrgSetName="ORG SET NAME">
            <EntryList>
                <OrgSetEntry
                  EffectiveDate="02/09/2018"
                  Name="ROOT/BU/DIVISION/SERVICE LINE/DEPT/JOB"/>
            </EntryList>
        </OrgSet>
    </Request>
</Kronos_WFC>
```

If you want to add more than one job, you can either use multiple `<OrgSetEntry>` tags, or use `name` as a semicolon-delimited list of full pathnames for jobs. (`Name="path1;path2;path3"`)